# Spring Boot's health actuator - WHEN is it UP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I cannot find any documentation on when Springs Health Actuator will return the UP status. Can you rely on all *`@Components`* being initialized? Will a *`@Controller`* be ready to serve requests?

Comment: Auto configured health indicators check the database, jmx etc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: So you cannot know when the application context has been fully initialized?

Comment: it is mainly for endpoints and databases. If you want to check for application context initialization, you can write the listener to check that.

Comment: ok, thanks! there is a "status" attribut on the top level, though. This must be application wide - and I am wondering what it tells us?

{
  "status" : "UP",
.....

Answer (score 3):

In order to test whether the application context is loaded, you can perform this custom implementation.

`@EventListener` - The method annotated with EventListener is triggered when the context is initialized.

In the below code, I have incremented the counter on successful initialization. When you hit the actuator health endpoint, you will get the status as UP.

**Sample implementation for context initialization health check:-**

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    private final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    public static int counter;

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOG.info("Increment counter :" + counter);
        counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        if (counter == 0) {
            return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", 500).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }
}
```

**Endpoint Spring boot version 5:-**

> http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

Spring actuator can check the database, web service endpoints, email server etc. It can provide the status for all these resources which are part of the application.

[Some default health indicators available](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators)

Comment: Thanks! Please allow to ask what the top-level "status:UP" is for? Is it an aggregated status of all resources maybe? I could not find any documentation on this. Well, I will actually test if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, it is the aggregated result.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful! Still unsure how a Spring actuator can report things before the Spring application context is running. The application context should not be considered a resource itself probably. I was going to add a health indicator to my RestController, but since it is just a Spring bean, it can only be UP as long as the Spring application is running. Should one add a health check for a Spring bean after all?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. In that case, actuator should run separately. You can use the properties to configure the server. management.server.port: 8080
management.server.address: localhost